# NameError 'Menu' is not defined Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting an error when trying to run this code the error is as follows:

NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Tkinter

class Navbar:
    menu = Menu()
    root.config(menu=menu)

    fileMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fileMenu)
    fileMenu.add_command(label='New', command=doNothing)
    fileMenu.add_separator()
    fileMenu.add_command(label='Settings', command=doNothing)
    fileMenu.add_separator()
    fileMenu.add_command(label='Quit', command=doNothing)
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.navbar = Navbar(self)
        self.navbar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Why do I get this error and what can I do to stop this error from occurring?

Comment: Do you have a function or class named menu?

Comment: Well, where is `Menu` defined? Did you mean `tk.Menu`? Also, why do you `import Tkinter` twice? Decide whether or not you want to alias it, and be consistent.

Comment: This question was edited to be a completely different question. I rolled it back to the original question so that the answers would make sense. If you have a separate question to ask, create another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Menu` is a command in the `Tkinter` module, just like `Tk` and `Frame` which you're also using. Since you are importing the module twice, you can call it like `Tkinter.Menu(...)` or `tk.Menu(...)`.

Normally you only want to do one import of Tkinter. My guess is that you're copying and pasting code from multiple sources. My recommendation is to do `import Tkinter as tk` and then use the prefix `tk.` for all tkinter functions. I think it makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: thank you for your help Bryan. As you can tell I am a new to programming. I am having this problem with the labels would you happen to know why I am going wrong. Thank you for your help again.